# Calculating error bars for Excel Linear Regression

Tags: regression, predictive-models, forecasting, linear-model, excel

I've ben sent a forecast of sales from a consultancy.  It uses Excel's LINEST function, taking 4 factors that seem to have affected sales in the past, and used them to make a prediction.

How do I go about adding error bars to this prediction?  I believe LINEST provides a standard error, but using that would give me constant error bars, and surely the error would increase the further inot the future we go?

(Please note, I am not a statistician, so be gentle!)

Thanks!

Comment: If you find the duplicate does not have enough detail, check out other similar questions by searching on [regression prediction limit](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=prediction%20limit%20regression).